# Deploy en React

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, npm, github-pages

Estoy intentando hacer el deploy de un proyecto con React en gh-pages.

Link del repositorio: https://github.com/isturiz/daily-tasks

Link del sitio: https://isturiz.github.io/daily-tasks/

Cuando lo corro en local con `npm start` funciona sin problemas, pero al hacer el deploy la página queda en blanco. El archivo index.html.

Al hacer el deploy lanza el siguiente mensaje, no sé si haya alguna pista ahí

```
    $ npm run deploy

> daily-tasks@0.1.0 predeploy
> npm run build


> daily-tasks@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

[eslint]
src\App\AppUI.js
  Line 4:10:  'TaskSearch' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  48.11 kB  build\static\js\main.20d50acc.js
  1.43 kB   build\static\css\main.52e0f663.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment


> daily-tasks@0.1.0 deploy
> gh-pages -d build

Published
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta modificar:

- En tu package.json modifica el nombre de la propiedad "homepages" a "homepage". Borras tu carpeta de build y haces otra ves el deploy.
- Si no te funciona modifica el valor de la propiedad de homepage:

  "homepage": "https://isturiz.github.io/daily-tasks/"

Comment: Muchas gracias, sí funcionó. Supongo que era una combinación de varios errores porque antes tenía la url por https y no funcionó, por eso la había cambiado a ssh. En resumen, tuve que hacer ambos pasos que mecionaste para arreglar el problemas. De nuevo, muchísimas gracias!